# How to set an responsive image with zoom in?

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

Say for example i have an png logo of 1920 and logo on the center with a bottom line extends until the end of the image... at desktop view its perfect to view.. but when it goes to media, the image got shrinked, so the logo in the center of the image becomes too small.. here is the example..

on desktop view

[image]

on mobile view

[image]

so my question is, is there any way to make the center part of the image zoomable on media devices?

Comment: Please share your code...

Comment: '.img-responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}'

Comment: As per information try this 
Give width 100% to parent div and child image {width:auto; max-width:100%; height:auto;}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this situation you can use css3 property.
Example:

```
.logo {
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5); /* you can change the value also */
   -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
}
```

Use this code for mobile device view port..

Comment: Thanks for "Up Voting" :)

Answer (score 0):

please use media query for properly displaying your logo as

```
@media (min-width:321px) and (max-width: 770px)
{
 #logo
 {
  height:80px;
  width:80px;
 }
}
```